# The truth set of the formula $\{x\mid x\subset A\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have an assignment where I have to work with *power sets*:

> Let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the set $\{ x ~|~ x \subseteq A \}$.

And I have 2 questions:

> 1. Is the set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ a truth set for the formula $\forall  x \exists y  (x \subseteq y)$? Justify your answer.
> 2. Is the set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ a truth set for the formula $\forall x \exists y  (x \subset y)$? Justify your answer.

The difference between the first and the second is that in the first $x$ could be $y$. But what I am not understanding is if this $x$ is referencing to the $x$ in the introduction of the problem.

What I am understanding is that for all subsets of A, there exists a $y$ such that $x$ (a subset of A) is a subset of $y$, which is A?

From this reasoning I can say that the firs is correct but the second not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a *truth set* is the set of "values" of $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds, where $\varphi(x)$ is a formula with a *free* variable $x$.

Thus we have to consider the formula :

> $(x \subseteq A)$

and its truth set will be $\mathcal P(A)$, because the formula $(x \subseteq A)$ holds exactly for those $x$ such that $x \in \mathcal P(A)$.

*Note* that $\emptyset \subseteq A$ as well as $A \subseteq A$; thus, both $\emptyset, A \in \mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your reasoning seems correct to me. In other words:

1. The first statement that for each set $x \in \mathcal P(A)$ there is another set $y\in \mathcal P(A)$ such that $x\subseteq y$. is indeed correct. For example take $y=A$ and this works for all $x$.
2. But in the second statement if you take $x=A$ then you cannot find $y$ such that $A\subset y$.